# HighCharts refresh size?

Tags: highcharts

When I expanding browser chart size is expanding according to the page size. But When I narrowing the browser, chart sizing is not working.

I dont initialize height and width. They are already default. (I think, 100%)

How Can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding an event on browser resize and then call redraw() on your chart instance. If that does not help you could always call the setSize method of the chart object. You find them both here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#object-Chart

Comment: I solved it. I used your suggestion. resize chart div in browser resize event. If you write your comment as answer than I will accept that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event on browser resize. Then you can call setSize on the chart instance. Please remember that this event fires repeatedly when the browser resizes, so I usually use setTimeout and clearTimeout to only call it after browser resize.

```
var timer;
function onBrowserResize(){
    if (timer){
          clearTimeou(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
          // your resize code

          timer = null;
    }, 300);
}
```

The code above will wait 300 milliseconds until it executes the function in setTimeout.